Url dinamica con Cypress
Buenas tardes a todos!!....me encuentro realizando una prueba con cypress en donde al hacer clic en un botón de imprimir, la url cambia al final
Ejemplo: https://xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx/com.xxxxxx.xxx.documento?10080
Si realizo clic en imprimir, el número 10080 cambia a 10081 y si en ese momento tuvo varias consultas, puede aparecer en 10090.
A continuación comparto el código que estoy utilizando, cambiando manualmente el número, lo cuál no es lo que me estaría sirviendo.
import 'cypress-iframe';
require('cypress-downloadfile/lib/downloadFileCommand');

class ProyectoCuatro_Po {
  visitHome() {
    let tiempo = 1000;
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx');
      cy.wait(tiempo);
    });
  }

  SeccionUno(usuario, contrasena, t) {
    let tiempo = t;
    if (usuario !== "") {
      cy.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'vUSERNAME')]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).type(usuario);
    }
    if (contrasena !== "") {
      cy.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'vUSERPASSWORD')]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).type(contrasena);
    }
    cy.wait(tiempo);
    cy.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'LOGIN')]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).click();
    cy.wait(tiempo);
  }

  SeccionDos(numeroActa, t) {
    let tiempo = t;
    cy.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'MENUTOGGLE_MPAGE')]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).click({ force: true });
    cy.wait(tiempo);
    cy.xpath("//span[contains(.,'xxxxxx')]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).click({ force: true });
    cy.wait(tiempo);
    cy.xpath("//span[contains(.,'xxxxxx')]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).click({ force: true });
    cy.wait(tiempo);
    cy.get('#vFILTROGENERAL').should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).type(xxxxxx);
    cy.wait(tiempo);
    cy.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'BUSCAR')]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).click({ force: true });
    cy.wait(tiempo);
    cy.xpath("//a[@class='ui right floated large blue label'][contains(.,'Consultar')]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).click({ force: true });
    cy.wait(tiempo);
    cy.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'TABSCONTROLContainerpanel1')][@href='#Tab_TabControl'][contains(.,'TASAS/SERVICIOS/OBJETOS')]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).click({ force: true });
    cy.wait(tiempo);
    cy.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'xxxxxx')]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).click({ force: true });
    cy.wait(tiempo);
    cy.xpath("(//label[contains(@for,'GRIDOBLIGACIONES')])[1]").should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 }).click({ force: true });
    cy.wait(tiempo);

    cy.xpath("//input[@id='IMPRIMIRCONTADO']")
      .should("be.visible", { timeout: 5000 })
      .click({ force: true });

     
    const dynamicValue = '10055'; 


    const pdfUrl = `https://xxxx.xxxxx.com/xxxxxx/com.xxxxxx.xxxx.aadeudacontadosellados2?${dynamicValue}`;

    cy.downloadFile(pdfUrl, Cypress.env('downloadDirectory'), 'aadeudacontadosellados2_impl.pdf');

    

      cy.wait(tiempo);

      cy.xpath("//a[@href='#'][contains(.,'AU')]").should('be.visible').click({force: true})
      cy.wait(tiempo)
      cy.xpath("//a[@href='#'][contains(.,'Salir')]").should('be.visible').click({force: true})
      cy.wait(tiempo)
    
    
  }
}//final

export default ProyectoCuatro_Po;

Agradezco la colaboración
Graciass!!!
